# Asymmetrical load distribution on Li-Ion cells within a battery pack

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am designing a battery pack with 18650 Li-Ion cells. Each cell is installed on a seperate PCB and the PCBs are connected over wires to form a 2s4p configuration. I am aware that this is not an ideal Li-Ion pack configuration as cells typically need to be connected to each other with the lowest resistance connection as possible. However, this is not possible for this application.

When the load is connected, the current is spread asymmetrical between the cells. The physically closest cell to the load will carry 50% of the load current and the farthest only 10%. The "good" news is, the load current is low and below 1/2 C for each cell.

I am aware that this will lead to increased balancing effort. How will such an asymmetrical load distribution affect lifetime and performance of the pack?

EDIT:
Refere to schematic below. The 5mOhm resistor represent the wires.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I believe you do not understand the way the batteries discharge on load. 0.005ohms at 3.7V can carry over 740 Amps.  The way you are wired, all the batteries will discharge relatively equally. Only thing I can see using this schematic is a *standard* 2S4P lithium pack...?

Comment: Please note the load on the left side with 3.5A. the 5mOhm represent the wires.

Comment: At the power you are using this battery pack there is basically negligible loss inside such low resistance wires. Pretty much every large size 2S4P lithium battery pack out there is wired like yours. As long as you don't need over 100Amps, your wiring is fine. The BMS will have no issues either.

Comment: But on the simulation I see that top left cell is discharged with 0.5C and top right cell only with 0.2C.